# Posting Saved in wrong database table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a very complex Ruby on Rails website. I did not code it and dont know much about Ruby on rails.

Site deployed on dual servers.

Postgresql 9.0
redis 2.6.13
ruby 1.9.3
Ruby on rails 3

I have added a new table and pretty much copied another (controller, model, views) everything seems to work correctly until i go to save a new record to database.

at the moment i am inserting all records manually into postgres using php scripting from a csv file.

everything works great except for saving the post from the site.. I can even Update the post on the ruby site that is manually entered thru the php script.

---

If i am missing anything that may need to be shown let me know i will post whatever is nessary

---

When i try to post a NEW Hotload on my site it saves to the Loads Table.

as you can see the form is posting correctly: (i will post everything step by step)

```
Started POST "/users/ezpost?method=get" for 108.235.52.160 at 2014-05-12 10:21:25 -0500
2014-05-12 10:21:25 INFO -- Processing by UsersController#ezpost as HTML
2014-05-12 10:21:25 INFO --   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"â", "authenticity_token"=>"+csx3CBTDOIejupX2YE9Dv3PkFrqR/de7QWD6AqhVic=", "post"=>{"user_id"=>"10181", "origin"=>"springfield, mo", "dest"=>"st louis, mo", "type"=>"hotload", "equipment_id"=>"8", "pickup"=>"2014-05-12", "comments"=>"Posted From LoadMax EZ-Post Form", "hotload"=>"true"}, "commit"=>"Post", "method"=>"get"}
2014-05-12 10:21:25 INFO -- Redirected to http://loadmax.com/hotloads/1?load%5Bcomments%5D=Posted+From+LoadMax+EZ-Post+Form&load%5Bdest%5D=st+louis%2C+mo&load%5Bequipment_id%5D=8&load%5Bhotload%5D=true&load%5Borigin%5D=springfield%2C+mo&load%5Bpickup%5D=2014-05-12&load%5Buser_id%5D=10181
2014-05-12 10:21:25 INFO -- Completed 302 Found in 36ms (ActiveRecord: 2.2ms)
2014-05-12 10:21:25 INFO -- 

Started GET "/hotloads/1?load%5Bcomments%5D=Posted+From+LoadMax+EZ-Post+Form&load%5Bdest%5D=st+louis%2C+mo&load%5Bequipment_id%5D=8&load%5Bhotload%5D=true&load%5Borigin%5D=springfield%2C+mo&load%5Bpickup%5D=2014-05-12&load%5Buser_id%5D=10181" for 108.235.52.160 at 2014-05-12 10:21:25 -0500
2014-05-12 10:21:25 INFO -- Processing by HotloadsController#show as HTML
2014-05-12 10:21:25 INFO --   Parameters: {"load"=>{"comments"=>"Posted From LoadMax EZ-Post Form", "dest"=>"st louis, mo", "equipment_id"=>"8", "hotload"=>"true", "origin"=>"springfield, mo", "pickup"=>"2014-05-12", "user_id"=>"10181"}, "id"=>"1"}
2014-05-12 10:21:26 INFO --   Rendered hotloads/show.html.haml within layouts/application (181.6ms)
2014-05-12 10:21:26 INFO --   Rendered shared/_navbar.html.haml (4.1ms)
2014-05-12 10:21:26 INFO --   Rendered shared/_footer.html.haml (0.2ms)
2014-05-12 10:21:26 INFO -- Completed 200 OK in 225ms (Views: 64.7ms | ActiveRecord: 150.3ms)
2014-05-12 10:21:26 INFO --
```

Step 1: Form

EZPOST (HTML)

```
<div class='row-fluid'>
<div class='form-inline form-horizontal'>
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/ezpost?method=get" id="ez_post" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="+csx3CBTDOIejupX2YE9Dv3PkFrqR/de7QWD6AqhVic=" /></div>
<input id="post_user_id" name="post[user_id]" type="hidden" value="10181" />
<div class='control-group'>
<div class='control-label'>
<label class="required" for="origin_Origin">Origin</label>
</div>
<div class='controls'>
<input class="span10" data-autocomplete="/loads/autocomplete_location_cs" id="post_origin" mandatory="mandatory" name="post[origin]" placeholder="City, ST" type="text" value="" />
</div>
</div>
<div class='control-group'>
<div class='control-label'>
<label for="dest_Destination">Destination</label>
</div>
<div class='controls'>
<input class="span10" data-autocomplete="/loads/autocomplete_location_cs" id="post_dest" name="post[dest]" placeholder="City, ST" type="text" value="" />
</div>
</div>
<div class='control-group'>
<div class='control-label'>
<label for="type_Type">Type</label>
</div>
<div class='controls'>
<select class="span10" id="post_type" name="post[type]"><option value="load">Load</option>
<option value="truck">Truck</option>
<option value="hotload">Premium</option></select>
</div>
</div>
<div class='control-group'>
<div class='control-label'>
<label for="equipment_Equipment">Equipment</label>
</div>
<div class='controls'>
<select class="span10" id="post_equipment_id" name="post[equipment_id]"><option value="1">Auto Carrier</option>
<option value="2">B-Train</option>
<option value="47">Blanket Wrap Van</option>
<option value="42">Flatbed &amp; Tarps or Van</option>
<option value="9">Flatbed - Sides</option></select>
</div>
</div>
<div class='ez_post'></div>
<hr>
<input class="btn btn-primary" name="commit" type="submit" value="Post" />
</form>

<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/info/10181/home?hidden=true&amp;method=get" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="+csx3CBTDOIejupX2YE9Dv3PkFrqR/de7QWD6AqhVic=" /></div>
<div class='post_load' hidden>
<div class='control-group'>
<div class='control-label'>
<label class="required" for="pickup_Pickup">Pickup</label>
</div>
<div class='controls'>
<input class="datepicker span10" id="post_pickup" mandatory="mandatory" name="post[pickup]" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" size="30" type="text" />
</div>
</div>
<input id="post_comments" name="post[comments]" type="hidden" value="Posted From LoadMax EZ-Post Form" />
</div>
<div class='post_hotload' hidden>
<div class='control-group'>
<div class='control-label'>
<label class="required" for="pickup_Pickup">Pickup</label>
</div>
<div class='controls'>
<input class="datepicker span10" id="post_pickup" mandatory="mandatory" name="post[pickup]" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" size="30" type="text" />
</div>
</div>
<input id="post_comments" name="post[comments]" type="hidden" value="Posted From LoadMax EZ-Post Form" />
<input id="post_hotload" name="post[hotload]" type="hidden" value="true" />
</div>
<div class='post_truck' hidden>
<div class='control-group'>
<div class='control-label'>
<label class="required" for="available_available">Available</label>
</div>
<div class='controls'>
<input class="datepicker span10" id="post_available" mandatory="mandatory" name="post[available]" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" size="30" type="text" />
</div>
</div>
<input id="post_expiration" name="post[expiration]" type="hidden" value="2014-05-16" />
<input id="post_comments" name="post[comments]" type="hidden" value="Posted From LoadMax EZ-Post Form" />
</div>
</form>

</div>
</div>
```

UserController:

```
  def ezpost
    type = params[:post].delete(:type)
    Resque.enqueue(UserPoster, params[:post])
    redirect_to :controller => "#{type}s", :action => 'show', :id => 1, :load => params[:post]
  end
```

Hotload Controller: (at this stage it pulls the right View Page.)

```
  def show
    if params[:hotload]
      params[:hotload][:origin] = Location.to_point(params[:hotload][:origin])
      params[:hotload][:dest] = Location.to_point(params[:hotload][:dest])
      @hotload = Hotload.new(params[:hotload])
      @hotload.updated_at = Time.now
      @hotload.id = -1
      authorize! :show, @hotload
      flash.keep[:notice] = 'Please be aware that it could take up to 5 minutes for your hotload to appear in search results.'
    elsif params[:load]
      params[:load][:origin] = Location.to_point(params[:load][:origin])  unless params[:load][:origin].blank?
      params[:load][:dest] = Location.to_point(params[:load][:dest]) unless params[:load][:dest].blank?
      @hotload = Hotload.new(params[:load])
      @hotload.updated_at = Time.now
      @hotload.id = -1
      authorize! :show, @hotload
      flash.keep[:notice] = 'Please be aware that it could take up to 5 minutes for your truck to appear in search results.'
    else
      @hotload = Hotload.find(params[:id])
      @return_hotloads = Hotload.return_hotloads(@hotload)
      @return_loads = Load.return_loads(@hotload)
      authorize! :show, @hotload
    end
  end
```

Workers: user_poster

```
class UserPoster
  @queue = :user_posting

  def self.perform(_post)
    post_type=Load
    post_type=Hotload if (_post['hotload'])
    post_type=Truck if (_post['available'])
    result=post_type.send("post",_post)
    Notification.check(result.id, post_type)
  end

end
```

Hotloads Controller (post)

```
  def post
    @hotload = {}
    #assign hotload to new_hotload unless new_hotload doesn't exist. new_hotload is passed over via ezpost on the home page.
    unless params[:new_load].blank?
      params[:new_load].delete(:expiration)
      params[:new_load].delete(:available)
      params[:new_load].delete(:type)
      params[:hotload] = params[:new_load]
    end
    @hotload = params[:hotload]
      unless params[:post].nil?
        @hotload[:type] = params[:post][:type] unless params[:post][:type].nil?
      end
    if params[:new_load].nil?
      @hotload[:equipment] = params[:equipment][0] unless params[:equipment].blank?
    else
      #equipment_id 34 means 'Call for Equipment Type.'
      params[:hotload][:equipment_id] = 34
    end
    if Resque.enqueue(UserPoster,params[:hotload])
      flash.keep[:notice] = 'Please be aware that it could take up to 5 minutes for your premium load to appear in search results.'
    else
      flash.keep[:error] = 'Something went wrong.'
    end
    redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => 1, :hotload => @hotload
  end
```

FULL Hotload model

```
class Hotload < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :user_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => [:origin, :dest, :equipment_id, :length, :ltl, :pickup, :delivery, :rate, :weight]}
  attr_accessible :comments, :covered, :delivery, :dest, :equipment_id, :length, :ltl, :origin, :pickup, :rate, :user_id, :weight
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :equipment
  set_rgeo_factory_for_column(:origin, RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory(:srid => 4326))
  set_rgeo_factory_for_column(:dest, RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory(:srid => 4326))
  before_save :add_city_and_state

  def self.post(post)
    origin_state = post['origin'][-2,2]
    origin_city = post['origin'].gsub(%r(, [a-zA-Z]+), '').strip 
    dest_state = post['dest'][-2,2]
    dest_city = post['dest'].gsub(%r(, [a-zA-Z]+), '').strip 
    origin = Location.first(:conditions => {:city => origin_city.downcase, :state => origin_state.downcase}) 
    dest = Location.first(:conditions => {:city => dest_city.downcase, :state => dest_state.downcase})
    if origin.nil? or dest.nil?
     origin = Location.where("levenshtein(city, '#{origin_city.downcase}') <= 4 AND state = '#{origin_state.downcase}'").first
     dest = Location.where("levenshtein(city, '#{dest_city.downcase}') <= 4 AND state = '#{dest_state.downcase}'").first
    end
    post['origin'] = "POINT (#{origin.coords.x} #{origin.coords.y})"
    post['dest'] = "POINT (#{dest.coords.x} #{dest.coords.y})"
    l = Hotload.new(post)
    k = post.keys
    k.each do |key|
      if post[key] = ''
        post.delete(key) 
      end
    end
    l.save!
    l
  end

  def self.suggested_hotloads(user_id)
    @user = User.find(user_id)
    now = Time.now.strftime("%F")
    user_notifier = Notification.where(user_id: @user.id).first
    user_zip = @user.company.zip
    user_location = Location.where(zip: user_zip).first
    @suggested_hotloads = []
    begin
      notifier_hotloads = Hotload.where("origin = '#{user_notifier.origin}' OR dest = '#{user_notifier.dest}' AND pickup > '#{now}'").limit(25).order('id DESC')
      notifier_hotloads.each {|x| @suggested_hotloads.push x } if notifier_hotloads
    rescue Exception => e
      unless user_notifier.blank?
        if !user_notifier.origin.blank?
          notifier_hotloads = Hotload.where("origin = '#{user_notifier.origin}' AND pickup > '#{now}'").limit(25).order('id DESC')
        elsif !user_notifier.dest.blank?
          notifier_hotloads = Hotload.where("origin = '#{user_notifier.dest}' AND pickup > '#{now}'").limit(25).order('id DESC')
        end
        notifier_hotloads.each {|x| @suggested_hotloads.push x } if notifier_hotloads
      end
    end
    begin
      location_hotloads = Hotload.where("origin = '#{user_location.coords}' OR dest = '#{user_location.coords}' AND pickup > '#{now}'").limit(25).order('id DESC')
      location_hotloads.each {|x| @suggested_hotloads.push x } if location_hotloads
    rescue Exception => e
      puts e unless Rails.env.test?
    end
    @recents = Hotload.where("rate > 0 AND pickup > '#{now}'").order('id DESC')
    @recents.each do |recent|
      if @suggested_hotloads.count < 50
        @suggested_hotloads.push recent
      end
    end
    return @suggested_hotloads
  end

  def self.return_hotloads(hotload)
    if hotload.delivery.blank? then hotload.delivery = Time.now end
    Hotload.where(
      "ST_Distance(origin, ST_GeomFromText('#{hotload.dest}')) <= 100*1609.334
      AND ST_Distance(dest, ST_GeomFromText('#{hotload.origin}')) <= 100*1609.334
      AND pickup BETWEEN '#{hotload.delivery}' AND '#{hotload.delivery+3.days}'
            AND equipment_id = '#{hotload.equipment_id}'"
    ).limit(5)
  end

  private
    def add_city_and_state
      origin = Location.city_state(self.origin)
      dest = Location.city_state(self.dest)
      if origin == "ANYWHERE"
        self.origin_city, self.origin_state = nil, nil
      else
        self.origin_city = origin[:city]
        self.origin_state = origin[:state]
      end
      if dest == "ANYWHERE"
        self.dest_city, self.dest_state = nil, nil
      else
        self.dest_city = dest[:city]
        self.dest_state = dest[:state]
      end
    end
end
```

tried to get my script to log errors but no such luck

```
class UserPoster
  @queue = :user_posting

  def self.perform(_post)
    post_type=Load
    post_type=Hotload if (_post['hotload'])
    @log.error _post['hotload']
    post_type=Truck if (_post['available'])
    @log.error _post['avaliable']
    result=post_type.send("post",_post)
    Notification.check(result.id, post_type)
  end
  @log = Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/userposter.log")
  @log.datetime_format = "%F %T"
end
```

Comment: where are you stuck exactly ?? can't understand from what have you explained above... can you be more specific

Comment: I have added the New Hotloads table. and for some reason i can not figure out why when i post a New Hotload it saves it into the Loads table instead. I am thinking it might be somewhere in the Workers because i have redis installed.

Comment: everything seems to work fine except for Saving to wrong table

Comment: I cant get it to log anything see my updated script at bottom of post for logging

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be in the `perform` method, since that's where the decision is made and the only code I can see that suggests a branching path to Load or Hoatload. It could be as simple as using symbols in the `_post` param. Try this.

```
class UserPoster
  @queue = :user_posting

  def self.perform(_post)
    post_type=Load
    post_type=Hotload if (_post[:hotload])
    post_type=Truck if (_post[:available])
    result=post_type.send("post",_post)
    Notification.check(result.id, post_type)
  end

end
```

Looks to me like it's setting post_type to Load right at the start and then `post_type` isn't returning True, so it ends up doing `Load.post _post` at the end.

If it's not that, you should work to figure out why _post['hotload'] is not returning true as expected. You can do Rails.logger.info _post['hotload'] to see its value. You may want to do `Rails.logger.info "The expected value is #{_post['hotload']}"` so you don't just get blank lines if it doesn't work at all.

Comment: i am unable to get any value on logger see above... i tried .info and .debug and .error

Comment: BTW  posting of a Truck works with the above code post_type=Truck if (_post['available'])   so it should be about the same for hotload

Comment: What if you just do `_post['hotload'].foo` and see what it reports when it crashes? You'll get a NoMethodError. If it comes from Nil, you know that you're not actually passing the value you expect. You could also try `puts _post['hotload']` and it will output to your server console.

Comment: You may also want to try `@logger.error "Expected output: #{_post['hotload']}"` so you know whether the logging failure is the result of something wrong with your logging or if it doesn't send anything to the log because it has nothing to tell you.

Comment: lol i am new to Ruby on Rails and with that script i cant find the log file any any of the log files that i know

Comment: In your app's folder, it'll be in `log/development.log` right at the base level of your application's folder. It will show the same thing as your `rails s` console output, though, so you can just watch for lines there.

Comment: I am on a windows computer and deploying to a Centos Server.. i am not able to run this site on this computer. and there is no log file created in that directory

Comment: Is your environment set to Production when you run the tests? If so, use `@logger.info` instead of `@logger.error`. Log file defaults to "log/production.log" in that case. Make sure you look at the base level of your application, the Log folder is at the same level as your Gemfile.

Comment: it definatly not in that log file... i look at that log file quite often and dont see anything in there

Answer (score 0):

After having a look at your log:

```
2014-05-12 10:21:25 INFO --   Parameters: {"load"=>{"comments"=>"Posted From LoadMax EZ-Post Form", "dest"=>"st louis, mo", "equipment_id"=>"8", "hotload"=>"true", "origin"=>"springfield, mo", "pickup"=>"2014-05-12", "user_id"=>"10181"}, "id"=>"1"}
```

It could be that your `redirect_to` code is passing `:load` as `params[post]` when it should be `:hotload`. Would it work if you added a second alternative `redirect_to` code in the UserController:

```
    def ezpost
        type = params[:post].delete(:type)
        Resque.enqueue(UserPoster, params[:post])

        if params[:post][:type] == "load"
           redirect_to :controller => "#{type}s", :action => 'show', :id => 1, :load => params[:post]
        elsif params[:post][:type] == "hotload"
           redirect_to :controller => "#{type}s", :action => 'show', :id => 1, :hotload => params[:post]
        else #truck
           redirect_to :controller => "#{type}s", :action => 'show', :id => 1, :truck => params[:post]
        end
    end
```

I haven't tested the code but hopefully it'll help

Comment: I have it passing as load because i use the form for 3 different types of postings. load, hotload, truck. once it gets to the proper controller ex hotload. i have  @hotload = Hotload.new(params[:load])...  but it should be saving before it gets there from users controller... Resque.enqueue(UserPoster, params[:post])

Comment: thanks for clarifying, your Rails code is very advanced indeed. I just had a look at Resque at RailsCasts which was totally new to me. http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque Apparently, there could be some delay involved but I'm not sure does it have any effect in this case

Comment: Did find out what the issue was? Well I just added truck to def ezpost just in case.

Comment: that part there works perfectly fine. the part that is not working right is Resque.enqueue(UserPoster, params[:post])